# Why is this tooltip still enabled?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I am working on a WPF app, and I am trying to make a tooltip conditionally enabled. It was being odd, and I realized that even when I explicitly set the tooltip to not enabled (`ToolTipService.IsEnabled="False"`), the tooltip still shows up. Can anyone figure out what is going on here?

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="0"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    FontSize="15"
    ToolTipService.IsEnabled="False"
    Visibility="{Binding IsConnected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="{Binding Path=BatteryLevelIcon, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
       Height="20"
       Width="20"
       Foreground="Green"
       Visibility="{Binding IsConnected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
       <TextBlock>
          <TextBlock.Text>
             <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}%">
                <Binding Path="BatteryPercentage" />
             </MultiBinding>
          </TextBlock.Text>
       </TextBlock>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
 </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled = false;`

[ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showondisabled?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Controls_ToolTipService_ShowOnDisabled)